# Rainmeter '!SetVariable' fails to work run in command line

Tags: window-position, rainmeter

I have a couple of Rainmeter skins on top of my taskbar that act as a cooler clock, and in order to keep the skins above the taskbar, I have the following code:

```
[Rainmeter]
Update=500
OnUpdateAction=!ZPos #ZAxis#

[Variables]
ZAxis=1
```

So that keeps the skins above the taskbar, but it also keeps it above things like youtube running fullscreen. I got an AutoHotKey script that will run a program when a window becomes fullscreen and when it closes fullscreen, so I told it to launch `"%PathToRainmerer%\Rainmeter.exe" !SetVariable "ZAxis" "-1" Skin.ini` and `"1"` on the un-fullscreen, but nothing happened.

I checked everything to make sure the AHK script was working, and I even tried to run `Rainmeter.exe` with the parameters using a shortcut, but nothing worked. I also set up a Meter with `Text=#ZAxis#` and it stayed at one. I'm guessing the issue is with the syntax, but I can't find proper documentation (probably because I'm so bad at researching). I can provide more details on polite request.

*Please remember that kind and respectful comments are greatly appreciated.*

Answer (score 2):

Try "\pathtorainmeter\rainmeter.exe" !activateconfig "mainskin folder\skin subfolder" "skin.ini"

Worked for me